# Enumeration style with letters but overlapping

Tags: enumerate, enumitem, etaremune

I'd like to use letter style enumeration for two running lists, combined into one.

The two lists have letter enumeration J-journals and C-conference. Code and output below for the two lists.

Once combined as one single list, it would allow overlapping **J** and **C** items. such as: J3 C2 J2 J1 C1

```
Journal list:
\begin{etaremune}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{J\arabic{enumi}}
\item Journal 1
\item Journal 2
\end{etaremune}

Conference list:
\begin{etaremune}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{C\arabic{enumi}}
\item Proceeding 1
\item Proceeding 2
\end{etaremune}
```

[image]

Comment: You mean that the numbers will be counted down, like J5 -> C5 -> J4 -> C4 -> ... -> J1 -> C1?

Comment: Not exactly, I can list journals and conference items together but they are counted separately, the journals with a J and conference items with a C. They are both counted down of course descending order. I have updated my question, does it help?

Comment: it is always better to post a small test document rather than a fragment in particular it would show where you are defining etaremune

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a package that does this, so below is effectively a reimplementation of [`etaremune`](https://ctan.org/pkg/etaremune) that uses two counters instead of one.

The `jcenum` environment defined below is defined using `itemize`. It can contain two types of items, declared with `\jitem` and `\citem` which correspond to journals and conferences respectively.

```
\documentclass{article}

%% Counter for jcenum environments:
\newcounter{jcenum}

%% Separate counters for journals and conferences:
\newcounter{enumj} %% <- counts journals
\newcounter{enumc} %% <- counts conferences
\renewcommand*\theenumj{J\arabic{enumj}}
\renewcommand*\theenumc{C\arabic{enumc}}

%% A new enumeration environment based on itemize:
\makeatletter %% <- make @ usable in macro names
\newenvironment{jcenum}{%
  \stepcounter{jcenum}%
  \@ifundefined{enumjmax@\arabic{jcenum}}{\@namedef{enumjmax@\arabic{jcenum}}{0}}{}%
  \@ifundefined{enumcmax@\arabic{jcenum}}{\@namedef{enumcmax@\arabic{jcenum}}{0}}{}%
  \setcounter{enumj}{\@nameuse{enumjmax@\arabic{jcenum}}}%
  \setcounter{enumc}{\@nameuse{enumcmax@\arabic{jcenum}}}%
  \itemize
}{%
  %% Write the number of journals/conferences to the aux files:
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    \string\global\string\@namedef{enumjmax@\arabic{jcenum}}%
      {\the\numexpr\@nameuse{enumjmax@\arabic{jcenum}}-\value{enumj}+1}%
    \string\global\string\@namedef{enumcmax@\arabic{jcenum}}%
      {\the\numexpr\@nameuse{enumcmax@\arabic{jcenum}}-\value{enumc}+1}%
  }%
  \enditemize
}
\makeatother  %% <- revert @

%% Separate \item macros for journals and conferences:
\newcommand*\jitem{\addtocounter{enumj}{-2}\refstepcounter{enumj}\item[\theenumj.]}
\newcommand*\citem{\addtocounter{enumc}{-2}\refstepcounter{enumc}\item[\theenumc.]}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{First environment}

\begin{jcenum}
\jitem First journal \label{firstitem}
\citem First conference
\citem Second conference
\jitem Second journal
\citem Third conference
\end{jcenum}

\noindent Reference to the first item: \ref{firstitem}

\subsection*{Second environment}

\begin{jcenum}
\jitem First journal
\citem First conference
\citem Second conference
\end{jcenum}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

#### A few words on what this does:

I define the counters `enumj` and `enumc` to keep track of the journal and conference index. 
These are decremented whenever `\jitem` or `\citem` is called and at the end of the `jcenum` environment their correct starting values are calculated and written to the aux file. 
On the second run, the starting value that was stored in the aux file is applied to `enumj` and `enumc` at the start of the `jcenum` environment (otherwise `0` is used).

The `jcenum` counter is there to generate identifiers for the individual `jcenum` environments in case your document contains multiple `jcenum` environments.